# Python to run geopy via ActivePython

Tags: python, google-maps, activepython, geopy, pypm

Trying to get a location using Python and Google Maps, so I tried to use [Geopy](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/geopy/) module by installing activepython using `pypm install geopy` but i get a problem which is  geo required  business  edition subscription. Can any one help me?
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> geo required business edition subscription

No. You are probably using the Windows 64-bit build, which requires Business Edition to install all packages (as even [this page](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/geopy/) should tell you with the "lock" icon).

Try the 32-bit version instead.